# What is the height of Kei Shirogane?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

Well we know Miko Iino is 147cm. There have been deductions for other characters based on this image from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kaguya_sama/comments/gqqeix/i_used_frames_from_s2_to_determine_the_height_of/) (by user TheBlueInk1) which estimates height based on Miko Iino's stated height of 147cm (S02E04):

[image]

What about Kei Shirogane?

Note: [In the dub, Miko Iino is stated to be 4'8", which is 142.24cm. But in the original, it's really 147cm.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66706/why-are-the-kaguya-sama-characters-shorter-in-the-dub) Following the dub, I guess we just subtract everything by 4.76 cm.

Comment: Why are they all on tiptoes? Surely that would skew the results.

Comment: @Daron Thanks for commenting. Interesting... Maybe it's a skewed perspective like the floor is leaning down because of an elevated angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh *at least in the anime* Kei and Kaguya are the same height of 158cm or 5'2.2". See here: [Who is taller, Kaguya or Kei?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66764/who-is-taller-kaguya-or-kei)

Or I'll just copy it.

[image]

Source: https://twitter.com/mazacon_ha_saka/status/1520315594402562048

Comment: They are on tiptoes here too! What is up with that? If you look at the 169cm man you can see his foot is sideways and he is on tiptoes. So it is not to do with perspective.

Comment: @Daron Hell. Good point. Thanks. The other case I can say floor is skewed. Here not sure... but maybe the floor is skewed in the other case and then it's just a cut out here?

Comment: @BLC My current theory is it's a convention when drawing character models to cram more visual information in there. Maybe it indicates how to draw how much the shoe bends when the character walks? It is kind of accurate that if you look from face height and close up you will see the top of the shoe and less of the front. But to complicate things the pink hair girl IS actually on tiptoes.

Comment: @Daron Ah Fujiwara-shoki aka Shoki no Chika. Maybe just a slight lean on 1 foot but overall doesn't affect the height? Idk

Comment: It probably indicates that she is cheerful.

Answer (score 3):

**Can't give so precise an answer, but I can give a range estimate,** depending on [who is taller between Kaguya and Kei](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66764/who-is-taller-kaguya-or-kei).

---

Answer 1:

I guess Kei is shorter than Kaguya but taller than Chika (Fujiwara) based on the aforementioned image from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kaguya_sama/comments/gqqeix/i_used_frames_from_s2_to_determine_the_height_of/) and based on the following from S01E08

> [image]
>
> [image]

This puts Kei's height

- between 151cm (4'11.4") and 156cm (5'1.4") for the original Japanese
- and then between 146.24cm (4'9.5") and 151.24cm (4'11.5") for the dub.

---

Answer 2:

Wait it could be that Kei is taller than Kaguya (but still shorter than Yu (Ishigami)) based on the aforementioned image from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kaguya_sama/comments/gqqeix/i_used_frames_from_s2_to_determine_the_height_of/) and based on the following from S02E02

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

This puts Kei's height

- between 156cm (5'1.4") and 164cm (5'4.6") for the original Japanese
- and then between 151.24cm (4'11.5") and 159.24cm (5'2.7") for the dub.