# Who is taller, Kaguya or Kei?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

I guess Kei Shirogane is shorter than Kaguya based on the following from S01E08

> [image]

But it could be that Kei is taller than Kaguya based on the following from S02E02

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: This question and https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66626/what-is-the-height-of-kei-shirogane/66769 are extremely similar in nature. If you wish to ask a question about character heights in general please choose one of your questions and edit the scope. Comparing character heights does not necessarily distinguish it from another. One of them will be closed due to how closely they overlap with one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh *at least in the anime* Kei and Kaguya are the same height of 158cm or 5'2.2".

[image]

Source: https://twitter.com/mazacon_ha_saka/status/1520315594402562048