# Why is Raiha Uesugi much taller in 1 particular scene?

Tags: the-quintessential-quintuplets

In S01E04, Raiha is about up to the quints' lower necks.

> [image]

In S02E11, Raiha's (relative) height seems to be about the same.

> [image]

But in S02E02, Raiha is somehow almost as tall as Itsuki, like up to Itsuki's forehead. What's going on? (Minor spoiler for S02E02)

> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a non-spoiler answer:

In Ch2, Raiha is standing on a footstool:

> [image]

So presumably in S02E02, *whatever is happening in that scene* and *wherever* that scene takes place, Raiha is probably standing on a footstool or something.

Answer (score -1):

It's just that the studio doing the animation did not pay that much attention to these details. If you are meticulous enough, you will discover deficiencies like this in many anime. It's in fact a common pitfall for animation studios.

There are also deficiencies in anime other than height. For example, the location of the mouth is also widely criticized. As you can see in the scene below from *Sora no Method*, the girl's mouth is totally on the left-hand side of her face, which would be considered as abnormal in real life. [image]

Comment: Michael, how did you know (Gasai) that the studio did not pay much attention to detail rather than that you think *maybe* the studio didn't? I posted an answer just now based on the manga that I believe answers this. However, you may be interested in my other question [What is the height of Kei Shirogane?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66626/what-is-the-height-of-kei-shirogane)

Comment: Reminds me of the chapter in Nozaki-kun where his inconsistent height issues are remarked and he responds that he just draws the characters standing on boxes to fix it (and that carrying boxes around is popular in-universe).

Comment: But really...a 9 year old girl same height as a 17 year old girl in the middle of a season only for no particular comedic reason? Come on

Comment: @BCLC You won't be surprised by this kind of height inconsistency if you have watched *Detective Conan* and payed attention to its awful height variation.

Comment: @BCLC If the studio have payed enough attention to this, then they should tell the audience what cause this sudden 'change' in height rather than left out the cause and let the audience try to guess the reason. It's just like that a good anime should be self-contained and tell the full story rather than make it a job of audience to make up for it by using their imagination or reading the original manga.

Comment: 'It's just that the studio doing the animation did not pay that much attention to these details.' - would you consider adding an 'I think' to this sentence?

Answer (score -3):

Ok actually, the scene in the spoiler image in the question doesn't exactly happen in the manga, BUT...

There's a similar scene in the manga around [Chapter 40-42 (which is adapted into S02E02](https://5hanayome.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_14), the episode in question). You can see that Raiha is again up to Itsuki's forehead in, what I believe is, a similar situation as in the spoiler image in the question post.

> [image]

To say explicitly:

> Raiha is standing on a footstool.